# PHP telnet array reply parsing to store on mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, telnet

Hi guys i have a small project going on, and this project requires me to send a cmd via telnet to a device and i get a reply and it troughs out the ansewer on a array.. i need to parse this data só i can store in on a mysql table..

this is the data output reply from the telnet cmd..

```
 Array ( 
 [0] => show ont info 0/0 4 all 
 [1] => ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
 [2] => F/S P ONT MAC Control Run Config Match Desc 
 [3] => ID flag state state state 
 [4] => ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
 [5] => 0/0 4 1 70:A8:E3:B4:5C:5C active online success match 
 [6] => 0/0 4 2 E0:67:B3:7E:20:05 active online success match 
 [7] => 0/0 4 3 E0:67:B3:7D:F8:F9 active online success match 
 [8] => 0/0 4 4 E0:E8:E6:4E:69:B8 active online success match 
 [9] => ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
 [10] => Total: 4, online 4 
 [11] => 
 [12] => OLT(config)# 
 [13] => 
 [14] => OLT(config)# 
 )
```

basically i need to separate F/S 0/0   P = 4     ONT ID = 1,2,3,4 depending ond cmd reply this can vary up to 64 devices , MAC CONTROL= device mac. xx:xx:xx:xx:xx  RUN =active   Config= online,   MATCH DESCRIPTION = success match

on the mysql table we have the following rows

```
 FRAME SLOT = 0/0 
 PON = PON DEVICE Number
 ONT ID = ID of devices
 MAC CONTROL
 RUN
 CONFIG
 MATCH DESC
```

i am kind of lost i have tried foreach to filter it .. but its not storing the data correctly...

edit-1

ok so i can explode the array and filter the details but i am stuck on the loop now.. its just filtering the lad ONT id device data.. i triead a foreach but its not working.. attached code below and picture its only filtering the last ONT ID and outputing the result.[pic-test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oljWT.png)

```
/*PON4*/
   $show_pon4[0] = "show ont info 0/0 4 all";
   $telnet->DoCommand($show_pon1, $pon4_reply);
   $showpon4_res_exp = explode("\n", $pon4_reply);
   for ($h=0; $h<=count($showpon4_res_exp); $h++) {

                if (strpos($showpon4_res_exp[$h], "ID") !== FALSE) {
                        $j=1;
                        do{
                            $returns = str_replace ( "                   ", " ", $showpon4_res_exp[$h+1+$j]);
                            $returns = str_replace ( "    ", " ", $returns);
                            $returns = str_replace ( "    ", " ", $returns);
                            $returns = str_replace ( "    ", " ", $returns);
                            $returns = str_replace ( "  ", " ", $returns);
                            $returns = str_replace ( "  ", " ", $returns);
                            $returns = str_replace ( "  ", " ", $returns);
                            $dt_returns = explode(" ", trim($returns)); 
                            //die(print_r($dt_returns, true));
                            $fsp = str_replace ( "epon-slot_", "", $dt_returns[0]);
                            $fspExp = explode("/", $fsp);                     // Frame e slot from OLT 0/0  
                            $ret["returns"][$j]["frame"] = $fspExp[0];        // Read Frame 0
                            $ret["returns"][$j]["slot"] = $fspExp[1];         // Read Slot  0
                            $ret["returns"][$j]["pon"] = $dt_returns[1];              // Returns PON Nº
                            $ret["returns"][$j]["ont_id"] = $dt_returns[2];           // ONT ID 
                            $ret["returns"][$j]["mac"] = $dt_returns[3];              // Returns MAC
                            $ret["returns"][$j]["control-flag"] = $dt_returns[4];     // Returns Control Flag
                            $ret["returns"][$j]["run-state"] = $dt_returns[5];        // Returns Run-State
                            $ret["returns"][$j]["config-state"] = $dt_returns[6];     // Returns Config-State
                            $ret["returns"][$j]["match-state"] = $dt_returns[7];      // Returns Match-state
                        
                                                  

                            
                            $j++;
                        } while( strpos($showpon4_res_exp[$h+1+$j],"-----------------------------------------------------------------------------") === false );

                        $qtdOnts += $j;
                      
                    }

                 

                $ret["info"][0]["qtd"] = $qtdOnts; 
                
            }
```

Comment: Show the code you tried, show the way in which it did not work, and we can suggest improvements. As it stand this question is simply "please write my code for me".

Comment: Hi, basically i have not created any code yet because i am lost on how to parse it.. maybe using preg_match ? trying yet..

Comment: Assuming that there are always 4 lines of preamble, start a `for()` or `while()` loop at line 5, and stop when the line is all `----`. Then for each line just `explode()` and you've got your bits to work with.

Comment: Thanks i will give it a try... so in theory on line 4 -------------

Comment: while( strpos($test[$h+1+$j],"-----------------------------------------------------------------------------") === false );

Comment: i did try to output but i cannot get the loop to work i can only filter the last device id.. here is the full log output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi guys late reply but eventually managed to get the code working update on the mysql table attached working code, there were some escape security caracteres on the telnet log which were breaking the output in the middle.
Obviously i must thank all the inputs from everyone (@sammitch and @jared) who participated on the replies and comments for helping me also, pointing me out on the correct steps...

> ```
> $show_pon[0] = "show ont info 1 all";
> ```

```
   $telnet->DoCommand($show_pon, $poninfo);
    
    
// Will replace numeric keys with these later
 
 $test = trim(str_replace('', '', $poninfo));
 $test2 = trim(str_replace('.', '', $test));
 $sections = preg_split('/-{50,}\s*\r?\n/s', $test2);
 $rows = preg_split('/\r?\n/', trim($sections[2]));

 $query_chunks = [];
 $query_data = [];
 


 foreach( $rows as $row )
{      
$query_chunks[] = "(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
$query_data = array_merge($query_data, preg_split("/\s+/", trim($row)));
}
//die(print_r($query_data, true)); 
$query = "INSERT INTO ont_onu (frame_slot, pon, ont_id, mac_address, control_flag, run_state, config_state, match_state, description) VALUES "  . implode( ', ', $query_chunks );

$pdo_dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=midebe', 'iuzer', 'pausord');
$sth = $pdo_dbh->prepare( $query );
$sth->execute( $query_data );

die(print_r($query_data, true));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should break the response into sections, then break section #3 into lines. Regexps are your friends:

```
// Will replace numeric keys with these later
$fields = ["frame","slot","pon","mac","control-flag","run-state","config-state","match-state"];

// Data is a raw string
$sections = preg_split('/-{50,}\s*\r?\n/s', $data);

// I asume your rows are always on section with index 2
// If not, we could autodetect it, matching section with a "/^\d\/\d/" regexp
$rows = preg_split('/\r?\n/', trim($sections[2]));

$entries = [];
foreach( $rows as $row ){

  $entry = preg_split("/\s+/", trim($row));

  // Move values from numeric keys to string keys
  foreach( $fields as $i => $field ){
    $entry[ $field ] = $entry[ $i ];
    unset( $entry[$i] );
  }

  $entries[] = $entry;

}

print_r($entries);
```

The following code should be inserting data in the MySql table via PDO:

```
// Data is a raw string
$sections = preg_split('/-{50,}\s*\r?\n/s', $data);

// I asume your rows are always on section with index 2
// If not, we could autodetect it, matching section with a "/^\d\/\d/" regexp
$rows = preg_split('/\r?\n/', trim($sections[2]));


$query_chunks = [];
$query_data = [];

foreach( $rows as $row ){

  $query_chunks[] = "(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
  $query_data = array_merge($query_data, preg_split("/\s+/", trim($row)));

}

$query = 
  "INSERT INTO ont_onu (frame_slot, pon, ont_id, mac_address, control_flag, run_state, config_state, match_state) VALUES "
  . implode( ', ', $query_chunks ) ;

$pdo_dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=DATABASE_NAME', 'DATABASE_USER', 'DATABASE_PASSWORD');
$sth = $pdo_dbh->prepare( $query );
$sth->execute( $query_data );
```

While you are running mysqli, not PDO, you have to construct query while going though rows:

```
foreach( $rows as $row ){

  $query_chunks[] = '('.implode(', ', array_map(function( $value ) use ($mysqli) {

    return "'" . mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $value) . "'";

  })).')';

}

$query = 
  "INSERT INTO ont_onu (frame_slot, pon, ont_id, mac_address, control_flag, run_state, config_state, match_state) VALUES "
  . implode( ', ', $query_chunks ) ;

mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
```

Or call `bind_param`:

```
$mysqli_sth = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, $query);
$mysqli_sth->bind_param(
  str_repeat('s', count( $query_data )),
  ...$query_data
);
```

But i'd suggest moving to PDO.

Comment: Hi Jared.. First of all thanks for your input, it has helped me to understand it better, and it worked i have managed to fetch the data, which i guess will be easier now to update on the mysql table to store the info.  here is the output result with your code tested.

Comment: Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [frame] => 0/0 [slot] => 4 [pon] => 1 [mac] => 70:A8:E3:B4:5C:5C [control-flag] => active [run-state] => online [config-state] => success [match-state] => match ) 
[1] => Array ( [frame] => 0/0 [slot] => 4 [pon] => 2 [mac] => E0:67:B3:7E:20:05 [control-flag] => active [run-state] => online [config-state] => success [match-state] => match ) 
[2] => Array ( [frame] => 0/0 [slot] => 4 [pon] => 3 [mac] => E0:67:B3:7D:F8:F9 [control-flag] => active [run-state] => online [config-state] => success [match-state] => match )

Comment: so now we have $entries = the output result of the arrays... what if i want to break the results now to update on a slq insert to store each value on a table row..

Comment: Well, inserting this into your DB table is trivial. Can you post the `SHOW CREATE TABLE your_table_name` query results?

Comment: hi @jared, basically i have a table name called  ont_onu , and inside i have the following rows..

Comment: hi @jared, basically i have a table name called  ont_onu , and inside i have the following columns on the code below
    
    
    //frame_slot
    //pon
    //ont_id
    //mac-address
    //control-flag
    //run-state
    //config-state
    //match-state
    // solicita tentativa de escrita na tabela ont_onu dos dados
       $sql = "INSERT INTO ont_onu (frame_slot, pon, ont_id, mac_address, control_flag, run_state, config_state, match_state) VALUES ('$frame_slot', '$pon', '$ont_id', '$mac_address', '$control_flag', '$run_state', '$config_state', '$match_state')";

Comment: but the output from $entries list all the array.. actually it splits is in each array of each device.. containing all the information, it looks like i need to filter all the output.. and do a sql insert of each device? with a loop? or can i forward all the replies from all devices at the same time inside the sql query?

Comment: I've updated the answer. Note, I didn't test the code.

Comment: Hi jared.. i will give it a try today

Comment: ERROR: Not possible to  execute INSERT INTO ont_onu (frame_slot, pon, ont_id, mac_address, control_flag, run_state, config_state, match_state) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?), (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?), (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?), (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?), (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?). You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?), (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?), (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?), (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?), (?...' at line 1

Comment: Please post a PHP source if you have changed code provided and a mysql `SHOW CREATE TABLE ont_onu` so i could reproduce you environment.

Comment: i posted it now the full code on your last post.. edited on it please check

Comment: Updated the answer for mysqli. Note, i did not test that code, it might need some fixes.

Comment: Hi jared, first of all thanks for your input,  has worked on PDO mode, on mysqli i could not manage to get it working still.. i will update the code of your pdo example, as i guess you have deleted by mistake the query_data code. and it needs to work properly and load data into the table.. and i will surely consider using PDO on the entire project.

Comment: Yep, removed query_data by mistake. If you find this solution helpfull, please consider accepting the answer ;)

Comment: Hi jared, i tried scanning other devices in other port.. and some ports only have 1 device enabled.. and it cannot output the result.. i think is relation to the sections code   $rows = preg_split('/\r?\n/', trim($sections[2]));     how can i configure a regexp "/^\d\/\d/" regexp  to autofind devices on ports with less devices connected ?

Comment: OLT(config)# show ont info 0/0 1 all
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  F/S  P  ONT MAC               Control   Run        Config   Match     Desc
          ID                    flag      state      state    state
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  0/0  1  1   AC:4E:91:A6:CF:F5 active    online     success  match     VILERMINA-.
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Total: 1, online 1                   This is the output on port with only 1 device

Comment: Can you attach a full output to parse (SO removes linebreaks)?

Comment: Hi attached output of query_data Array ( [0] => 0/0 1 1 AC:4E:91:A6:CF:F5 active online success match VILERMINA-. )

Comment: i have added another row on the mysql table with name description  and i can see it parses one extra data.. VILERMINA .. which should be added to description

Comment: '$query_chunks = [];
$query_data = [];

foreach( $rows as $row ){

  $query_chunks[] = "(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
  $query_data = array_merge($query_data, preg_split("/\s+/", trim($row)));
  die(print_r($query_data, true));
}

$query = 
  "INSERT INTO ont_onu (frame_slot, pon, ont_id, mac_address, control_flag, run_state, config_state, match_state, description) VALUES "
  . implode( ', ', $query_chunks ) ;
'